# Retrieved mails with POP3 are automatically deleted

Tags: php, email, pop3

I'm currently programming a little page with a function that retrieves the number of unread mails of my gmail inbox.

I am **not** trying to read the emails content nor deleting, moving or marking them.
I just want to get the number of unread emails.

As far as I remember, using pop3 should not delete any email unless the imap_delete function is called...

I'm using CakePHP, but it doesn't matter considering the length of the code...

```
    //connexion     
    $hostname = '{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'username@gmail.com'; 
    $password = 'passwd';

    //trying to connect -- works fine
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());      
    //retrieve UNSEEN emails only
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN'); 


    $nbEmails = count($emails); //find the number of emails

    imap_close($inbox); //close the connexion
```

I am not asking for any suppression here...
I also checked that my Gmail account settings were not wrong (I am keeping the original untouched).

I know the question might look silly (I could use imap for this, especially considering, but my project *requires* pop3.

Could you please tell me why emails are deleted even though I am not using `imap_delete`?

**EDIT :**

OK. I just tried the **same** code with another inbox (e.g not a gmail account), and it did **not** delete any emails...That's kind of awkward.. maybe Gmail automatically deletes any read emails when pop3 is used...I don't know.

Using the following code:

```
debug(imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0));
```

I found that the emails read were not marked as `deleted`.
I have no idea on how to understand all of this, but it is sure that not using gmail will allow me to continue working.

If someone find an explanation, I am willing to listen (well, read)!

Comment: You should start with explaining yourself that you *actually* use `imap`, not `pop3`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: because the imap_*() functions support pop3 as well. you specify the protocol exactly as the OP is in $hostname.

Comment: @mudasobwa well, as far as i know (i'm new with all of this), I understood that it is possible to use imap functions with `pop3`. I remember some functions doesn't work with `pop3` though.

See : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: Oooups. Beg your pardon and thanks for pointing me to that. `imap_search` works with imap streams only, though.

Comment: @mudasobwa No problem :) 
I'm surprised with what you said about `imap_search`, because i do retrieve my emails using it, and I can display their message, or whatever.
There really must be something I did not understand ><